# Как изменить шрифт Button?

Tags: android, шрифты

Пытался изменить шрифт кнопок. Создал папку в res/font, добавил шрифт и прописал код :

```
Typeface fontButton = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/helvetica_black.ttf");
btnAuthorization.setTypeface(fontButton);
```

Но приложение вылетает. В чем проблема ?

Comment: сделайте без указания папки `"font/"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить шрифт в res/font

Из кода
`btn.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.helvetica_black)`

Или xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_black"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала вам нужно поместить файл ttf в папку с ресурсами, а затем вы можете использовать приведенный ниже код для установки пользовательского шрифта в TextView, так же, как вы можете сделать для Button:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

<sup>[Поиск изменяет все!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372458/setting-button-text-font-in-android)</sup>

Comment: Так я так все и сделал. Я нажал ПКМ на папку res, затем прошелся по пути new - Folder -  Font Resources Folder . Добавилась папка Font, я в нее закинул шрифт и прописал код, который я добавил. И вылетает приложение

Comment: @Влад Тогда у вас ошибка где-то в другом месте.

Comment: Ответ, на который вы ссылаетесь, был дан 7 лет назад, раньше действительно так все и делали, только шрифт нужно добавлять в папку assets.

Comment: @katso А сейчас все поменялось?

Comment: @Ver Nick, после того как добавили поддержку Font resources необходимость в таком способе отпала.